# How to fix a tablet on car dashboard?

Tags: car, adhesive

I want to fix a 7-inch Android tablet on my car dashboard. It will be used as map navigator, music player (via Bluetooth) among other applications. Following images may help you understand the situation.

[image: interior of a car, Dashboard and AC controls in Focus.]

I want to fix it below AC controls. Can anyone suggest what kind of magnet or adhesive I should use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using something similar to this: 
https://www.amazon.de/Wicked-Chili-Blackberry-Autohalterung-kompatibel-schwarz-black/dp/B078JGCXK5/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1525376252&sr=8-4-fkmr0&keywords=ipad+autohalterung+l%C3%BCfter

You will have to look for a tablet-sized one, but the principle stays the same, and I know they exist, because we have one in our car. It attaches to the vents.